# Open tree in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have emacs file with tree

```
* Actions <hierarchical counter>
** Merge Down
*** Requested via Menu
*** Requested via Shortcut
```

How I can to сollapse or expand tree?

Comment: Use the menu in the menu-bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move point to the heading you want to collapse or expand, and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.  It will cycle between collapsing it entirely, showing only the headings of the child entries, and expanding all child entries.